# using CURL and avoiding being redirected to the base url

Tags: php, redirect, curl

Im trying to get the source code of a page with CURL

http://www.deindeal.ch/zurich/?a_aid=dealanzeiger&a_bid=62e0def7

but the only thing I get is the index site (http://www.deindeal.ch), as I would be redirected automatically. I suppose they are avoiding hotlinking or something like that? And in that case, how could I get the source code, maybe some curl setopt ?

My CURL connection:

```
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 60;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Take out this option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
```

However, if the site's redirecting, they may not output anything EXCEPT the redirect, so not following the redirect still won't get you any content, because they just flat-out don't send it.

Comment: +1 and likely because they set a session cookie that you don't have.